# Find key, value pair in dict according to second value of tuples using itemgetter() method

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have the following dictonary:

```
inventory = {'apple':(3, 133), 'banana':(9, 407), 'pear':(17, 205), 'orange':(1, 91)}
```

I would like to find key, value pair according to max value of the second element in the tuple so in this case it should return: `banana':(9, 407)`
I know I can get this result using `lambda`:

```
key_max = max(inventory.keys(), key=(lambda k: inventory[k][1]))    
print key_max, inventory[key_max]
```

However I try to receive same result using itemgetter() method as I read it is faster but I can only get data according to the value of first element of the tuple:

```
from operator import itemgetter 
print max(inventory.iteritems(), key = itemgetter(1))
```

Is there a way I could get same result using `itemgetter()` method?

Comment: Not that i know of :)

Comment: Also, `premature optimization is the root of all evil`, especially if you have a small dataset :)

Comment: I discourage `lambda`s when there are alternatives that don't make the code far more complex, partially for speed but more to make the code more self-documenting while excluding the possibility of a subtlety in the `lambda`). But I only do that so that when I see a `lambda`, I know it's doing something non-trivial. In this case, go for the `lambda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Although I don't see the point of this exercise...</sub>

Here's a solution using **only** `itemgetter` and **no lambdas**, as was the original question:

```
key = max(zip(inventory.keys(), map(itemgetter(1), inventory.values())), key=itemgetter(1))[0]

print(key, inventory[key])
# banana (9, 407)
```

Note that the above will only be efficient in Python **3.x** where the built-in functions return *iterators / view objects* instead of lists.

An equally efficient Python 2.x equivalent requires the use of library functions such as `itertools.izip`:

```
# from itertools import izip, imap

key = max(izip(inventory.iterkeys(), imap(itemgetter(1), inventory.itervalues())), key=itemgetter(1))[0]

print key, inventory[key]
```

Comment: Side-note: If you want to keep the code looking more similar, `imap`/`izip` are available with the normal names on [the `future_builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html) (so you can do `from future_builtins import map, zip` and the rest of the code looks the same as on Py3). Annoyingly, `future_builtins` doesn't exist on Py3, so for a cross-version code base, you'd need to wrap it in `try:`/`except ImportError: pass` so it's ignored on Py3. Add `from __future__ import print_function`, and the only difference on Py2 would be the `iter` prefix for `dict` methods.

Comment: Is this faster that the *lambda* (with all the *zip*, *map*, ...)?

Comment: @CristiFati that's not the point of my answer – I don't approve of premature optimization like this either. I was only answering OP's original question.

Comment: @CristiFati: It absolutely isn't. But it's fun, and the OP wanted it, so hopefully they learn that sometimes, rules like "avoid `lambda`s" exist to encourage you to do the right thing in general, knowing there are always exceptions (much in the same way regular expressions are discouraged in Python, up until trying to match them with slicing and string methods would be worse than the regex).

Answer (score 2):

Before I or someone else comes up with something fascinating:

```
inventory = {'apple':(3, 133), 'banana':(9, 407), 'pear':(17, 205), 'orange':(1, 91)}

maxVal = 0                   # to get the max of 2nd elem from tuple
for k,v in inventory.items():
    maxVal = max(maxVal, v[1])   

for k,v in inventory.items():
    if v[1] == maxVal:     # if the 2nd elem of tuple eqs to the maxVal
        print(k, v)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
banana (9, 407)
```

Note: I recommend the Edited version.

**EDIT**

Using `lambda`:

```
print(max(inventory.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))  # ('banana', (9, 407))
```

Comment: The OP asked, if he can do it using `itemgetter` :), because it is faster

Comment: @hansolo can't seem to get past that, perhaps a `lambda` approach would do in that case?

Comment: The *lambda* part was part of the question (as *OP* is aware of how to do it). The 1st part is ugly and highly inefficient. What's the end value? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @CristiFati  The first part was me before I got my caffeine! :3

Comment: Side-note: No need for indexing `v`. The loop can be `for k, (v1, v2) in inventory.items()` to unpack the values as well. Python is usually faster to unpack than to index, at least at function scope where it's cheap `STORE_FAST` instructions (and ideally, if the values have meaningful names, you can use them, instead of anonymous indexes).

Comment: @ShadowRanger aye. aye. Cap! :)

Comment: I upvote this answer because it’s the way to solve this problem. There is no need for `itemgetter`.